# What are Hotels on Salt Lake City Trax Light Rail?

Tags: public-transport, hotels, train-stations, snow, salt-lake-city

Going to SLC in late Feb for snowboarding. Looking at staying in Murray, downtown and South Salt Lake so closer to resorts (Alta, Brighton, etc).

- How do I find out what hotels are walkable to light rail stops?
- What is it like taking light rail/bus in winter conditions (with stroller)?
- Are rail stations at grade? any escalators or stairs?
- Or...Are we better off renting car to get around Salt Lake City?

Comment: You need a car - end of story!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well...I wouldn't worry about rail connections specifically.  There are no trains to any ski mountains.  The local transit authority instead runs busses to those mountains though the bus and train do share several stations.

Details here: [UTA Ski Service](https://www.rideuta.com/Services/Ski-Bus/UTA-Ski-Service)

Expedia chows a map of hotels you can cross reference with the bus lines.  Same with Airbnb.

However, if you're staying in Salt Lake, renting a car is by far the most practical, though the most expensive.  If you board, walking a block or two to the station is not the worst thing in the world.  If you ski...there's a reason they invented valet ;).

The experience is similar to an airport bus, just changing luggage for snow gear.

Comment: What about the days we're not skiing/snowboarding.  Would parking rental car at hotel then taking light rail be easier?

Comment: Like any city, it depends on where you want to go.  Salt Lake is not really transit oriented so you'd have to plan carefully.  Conversely, parking isn't usually a problem.